# Chemfig multiple brackets on the same bond

Tags: brackets, chemfig, chemistry

I'd like to draw the following copolymer structure using `\chemfig`.

[image]

But it turns out that I can't put the right bracket and the next left one within the same bond. All I found on the internet were some workarounds which I quite didn't understand.

The closest I got was

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}
\def\makebraces[#1,#2]#3#4#5{%
\edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
\edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
\chemmove{%
\node[at=(#4),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
{$\left\delimleft\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
width0pt\right.$};%
\node[at=(#5),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
{$\left.\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
width0pt\right\delimright_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle#3$}}$};}}
\setpolymerdelim()

\chemfig{H_2N-[:30](-[:90])-[:-30]-[@{L1,.75}:30]O-[:-30]-[:30](-[:90])-[@{R1}:-30]O(@{L2})-[:30]-[:-30]-[@{R2}:30]@{L3}O-[:-30]-[:30](-[:90])-[@{R3}:-30]NH_2}
\makebraces[20pt,20pt]{\!\!\!x}{L1}{R1}
\makebraces[20pt,20pt]{\!\!\!y}{L2}{R2}
\makebraces[20pt,20pt]{\!\!\!z}{L3}{R3}

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

As you see I can't displace the brackets that are on the Oxygen atom.
I'd care to get everything lined up as well.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

After checking [How to draw parentheses inside chemfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96633/how-to-draw-parentheses-inside-chemfig/96634#96634) as [Bobyandbob](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/124842/bobyandbob) told me so, I adapted the code a bit and got closer to what I want, but now I need the brackets to be bigger.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\def\L1{\llap{$\left(\strut\right.$\kern2pt }}
\def\Rx{\rlap{$\kern60pt \left.\strut\right)_x$}}
\def\Ry{\rlap{$\kern60pt \left.\strut\right)_y$}}
\def\Rz{\rlap{$\kern60pt \left.\strut\right)_z$}}

\chemfig{H_2N-[:30](-[:90])-[:-30]-[:30] \L1 \Rx O-[:-30]-[:30](-[:90])-[:-30] \L1 \Ry O-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30] \L1 \Rz O-[:-30]-[:30](-[:90])-[:-30]NH_2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Have you checked [How to draw parentheses inside chemfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96634/124842)? I think it solves your problem.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I just did, but still I can't get it done. The syntax seems to be a bit more clear though. The problem is putting two brackets in the same bond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [an older question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417808/47927) with a similar problem, of which the answer may also be a solution for you.

It makes use of a macro defined in the `polymers` module.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\newcommand{\makemypolymerdelims}[7][]{%
  \chemmove{\path (#6) -- node[pos=#4] {$\left(\vrule height#2 depth#3 width0pt\hspace{#5}\right)_#1$} (#7);}%
}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{H_2N-[:30](-[:90])-[:-30]-[@{a}:30]O-[:-30]-[:30](-[:90])-[@{b}:-30] O-[:30]-[:-30]-[@{c}:30]O-[:-30]-[:30](-[:90])-[@{d}:-30]NH_2}
\makemypolymerdelims[x]{8pt}{8pt}{.55}{60pt}{a}{b}
\makemypolymerdelims[y]{8pt}{8pt}{.55}{60pt}{b}{c}
\makemypolymerdelims[z]{8pt}{8pt}{.55}{60pt}{c}{d}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Vertical fine-tuning can be achieved by adding a `yshift` like in `\makemypolymerdelims[y]{8pt}{8pt}{.55,yshift=-.5pt}{60pt}{b}{c}` .

Answer (score 4):

I ended up finding a way of getting it round.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\def\L{\llap{$\left(\rule{0pt}{20pt}\right.$\kern0pt }}
\def\Ly{\llap{$\left(\rule{0pt}{20pt}\right.$\kern-78pt }}
\def\Rx{\rlap{$\kern60pt \left.\rule{-2pt}{20pt}\right)_x$}}
\def\Ry{\rlap{$\kern140pt \left.\rule{-2pt}{20pt}\right)_y$}}
\def\Rz{\rlap{$\kern60pt \left.\rule{-2pt}{20pt}\right)_z$}}

\chemfig{H_2N-[:30](-[:90])-[:-30]-[:30] \L \Rx \Ly \Ry O-[:-30]-[:30](-[:90])-[:-30]O-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30] \L \Rz O-[:-30]-[:30](-[:90])-[:-30]NH_2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Honestly I think it still could be better. The `x`, `y` and `z` are too far away from their respective right brackets, but I can live with that.

Anyway, if anyone happen to find a *more professional solution* I'd be glad to hear it!

Thanks!!

Comment: Forgot to say, all I did was change \strut to \rule. I'm really new to LaTex, but it seems to me that with \rule I have more control over the size and position of the brackets.

Comment: you can move the subscripts closer if you replace `_x` with `_{\!x}` for example