# Drawing a 'chair' representation with brackets

Tags: chemfig

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{
               % 8
              -O% 7
              -% 1
         -[:60]% 2
                  (
            -[:120]% 18
                      (
                =[:180]O% 20
                      )
         -[:60,,,1]OH% 19
                  )
              -O% 3
        -[:300]% 4
                  (
            -[:240]% 5
                      (
            -[:300,,,1]OH% 21
                      )
            -[:180]% 6
                      (
            -[:240,,,2]HO% 27
                      )
            -[:120]% -> 1
                  )
              -O% 9
              -% 10
         -[:60]% 11
                  (
            -[:120]% 22
                      (
                =[:180]O% 24
                      )
         -[:60,,,1]OH% 23
                  )
              -% 12
        -[:300]% 13
                  (
                  -O% 16
                  -% 17
                  )
        -[:240]% 14
                  (
        -[:300,,,1]OH% 26
                  )
        -[:180]% 15
                  (
            -[:120]% -> 10
                  )
    -[:240,,,2]HO% 25
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Hi, I am struggling to draw the diagram above. Could you please help me?

Comment: Well, please show us what you have tried so far ...

Answer (score 3):

Possible answer (also see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447983/47927) for reference), based on the examples for “chair” representations in the [ChemFig package documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf) (currently on page 38):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\newcommand{\makemypolymerdelims}[7][]{%
 \chemmove{\path (#6) -- node[pos=#4] {$\left[\vrule height#2 depth#3 width0pt\hspace{#5}\right]_#1$} (#7);}%
}

\begin{document}
\setchemfig{cram width=2pt}
\chemfig{
               % 8
              -[@{a}:10,,,,,dashed]O % 7 
              -[:10] % 1
         -[:-10] % 2
                  (
            -[:270] % 18
                      (
                =[:190]O % 20
                      )
         -[:-10,,,1]ONa % 19
                  )
              -[:10]O % 3
        -[:-50] % 4
                  (
            <[:-190] % 5
                      (
            -[:90,,,1]OH % 21
                      )
            -[:190,,,,line width=2pt,line cap=round] % 6
                      (
            -[:-190]HO % 27
                      )
            >[:130] % -> 1
                  )
              -[@{b}:10]O % 9 
              -[:10] % 10 
         -[:-10] % 11
                  (
            -[:90] % 22
                      (
                =[:-190]O % 24
                      )
         -[:10,,,1]ONa % 23
                  )
              -[:10] % 12
              -[:-50] % 13
                  (
                  -[@{c}:10]O % 17 
                  -[:10,,,,,dashed] % 16
                  )
        <[:-190] % 14
                  (
        -[:90,,,1]OH % 26
                  )
        -[:190,,,,line width=2pt,line cap=round] % 15
                  (
            >[:130] % -> 10
                  )
    -[:-190,,,2]HO % 25
}
\makemypolymerdelims[m]{10pt}{12pt}{.52}{125pt}{a}{b}
\makemypolymerdelims[n]{10pt}{12pt}{.55}{125pt}{b}{c}
\end{document}
```

Yielding:

[image]