# Bracket overlap with chemmacros

Tags: positioning, brackets, chemfig, chemmacros

I'm trying to position the brackets such that there is no overlap, while ideally aligning their vertical positions. The solutions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417792/chemfig-chemmacros-vertical-alignment-of-polymer-brackets) don't seem to help much. Also is there a way to move the subscripts closer to the right brackets? Any suggestions much appriciated!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={polymers}}
\setchemfig{atom sep = 2em}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{=[:150]-[:90] %middle branch
(-[@{c}:30]-[:330]=[:00]-[:30]-[@{d}:330]OH) %right branch
-[:150] -[@{b}:210] -[:150] =[:210] -[:150] -[@{a}:210]HO} %left branch
\makepolymerdelims[subscript={$x$},delimiters={()}]{7.5pt}{a}{b}
\makepolymerdelims[subscript={$z$},delimiters={()}]{7.5pt}{c}{d}
\makepolymerdelims[subscript={$y$},delimiters={()}]{7.5pt}{b}{c}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added more tags ("e" and "f") and adjusted the position of the double bonds

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={polymers}}
\setchemfig{atom sep = 2em}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig{=[:150]-[:90] %middle branch
        (-[@{c}:30,.5]-[@{f}:30,.5]-[:330]=^[:00]-[:30]-[@{d}:330]OH) %right branch
        -[:150] -[@{b}:210,.5]-[@{e}:210,.5] -[:150]=^[:210] -[:150] -[@{a}:210]HO} %left branch
    \makepolymerdelims[subscript={$x$},delimiters={()}]{7.5pt}{a}{e}
    \makepolymerdelims[subscript={$z$},delimiters={()}]{7.5pt}{f}{d}
    \makepolymerdelims[subscript={$y$},delimiters={()}]{7.5pt}{b}{c}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As a follow up to the accepted answer, I aligned the centre of all brackets to the mid point of the trans addition double bond (which I tagged "g") using the suggestion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417792/chemfig-chemmacros-vertical-alignment-of-polymer-brackets), and shifted the subscrpits left as shown below:

```
\makepolymerdelims[subscript={\!\!$x$},delimiters={()}]{7.5pt}{a|-g}{e|-g}
\makepolymerdelims[subscript={\!\!$z$},delimiters={()}]{7.5pt}{f|-g}{d|-g}
\makepolymerdelims[subscript={\!\!$y$},delimiters={()}]{7.5pt}{b|-g}{c|-g}
```

[image]

Comment: good sugestion. Don't forget to adjust the double bond below the molecule.